# Mystery Lines along Y-axis (ggplot2, R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am plotting time series data using ggplot and these mystery lines showed up when I set my x-axis as a date. Before I was just using concated string of year and month. The lines didn't show up then but I needed to convert my sale date variable to a Date class for the x scale to be correct. I haven't encountered this error on my other plots and I used the same function to convert my time variable to a date class.

My data has four columns, 1) a string with my sale date, 2) mean price of the quantile by month, 3) the quantile, 4) my sale date string but as Date class.

```
# Melt contains the sale date in string format, the value I want to plot, and quantile that mean corresponds to
  melt <- rbind(melt1, melt2, melt3, melt4, melt5)
  colnames(melt) <- c("saledate", "mean", "Quantile")

# Here I create my Date class variable to be plotted on the x axis
  melt$time <- lubridate::ymd(melt$saledate)
# So my legend is discrete  
  melt$Quantile <- as.factor(melt$Quantile)

  tiff(paste("./PLOTS/allquantiles_", varofinterest.string, ".tif"), width=6, height=5, res=200, units='in')
  a <- ggplot(melt, aes(x=time, y=mean, group=Quantile,
                        color=Quantile)) +
    geom_smooth() +
    xlab(paste(xlab)) + ylab(paste(ylab)) +
    ggtitle(paste("Average", varofinterest.title, "by Month: All Quantiles")) +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = 'bold', size = 14))
  print(a)
  dev.off()
```

My returned plot looks like this.. 
[image]

I've never encountered an issue like this with ggplot before. Any solutions or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Most likely your data is not in the correct format.  Can you edit the question paste a sample of your data, using the results from `dput(head(melt, 20))`

Comment: Looks like your "mean" variable (on the y-axis) has ended up as character or factor data, so ggplot is trying to create an axis showing every unique value. Ordinarily this would simply fail to plot correctly (since there would be 1 group for each data point), but your explicit call to `group=Quantile` ensures that only 5 groups get created for smoothing.

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you guys you were correct. The data did convert to a factor at some point but conversion back to numeric did the trick. Such a basic issue I didn't even think to check out - thank you for the reminder.